# how do i get the Port from an in_addr value?

Tags: vb.net, networking, in-addr

I am trying to extract the port from a given **in_addr** value in windows.

So far I am able to get the IP address using **inet_ntoa** but not the port.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not: it is [only an IP address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738571%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Perhaps you mean to use [sockaddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740496%28VS.85%29.aspx) which contains this information, when applicable.